# Tensorflow Splitting metadat same way as the image_dataset_from_directory

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have some images in folder respective to their classification.(i.e. under class 1 folder, there are all instances of class1 and same for other classes). Other than the images, each image also come with a few columns of metadata that could be useful for classification. This is how I've been splitting my test/validation/training:

```
traintest_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
            "input",
            seed=422,
            image_size=(self.RESIZED, self.RESIZED))
        train_ds = traintest_ds.take(train_size)
        test_ds = traintest_ds.skip(train_size)
        val_ds = traintest_ds.skip(test_size)
        test_ds = traintest_ds.take(test_size)
        train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
                "input", seed = 422,
                shuffle=True,
                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                image_size=(RESIZED, RESIZED),
                validation_split=0.4,
                subset='training')
        val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
                "input", seed = 422,
                shuffle=True,
                batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                image_size=(RESIZED, RESIZED),
                validation_split=0.4,
                subset='validation')
        val_batches = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(val_ds)
        test_ds = val_ds.take(val_batches // 2)
        val_ds = val_ds.skip(val_batches // 2)

        AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
        train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
        val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
        test_ds = test_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
```

I was wondering, how do I do the same split for my metadata. The metadata is in a csv file, with a column being the name of the images as identifier.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator) and [flow_from_dataframe](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdataframe-method).

Below is a helper class which can serve as an example.

In `_datagen` which is `ImageDataGenerator` you specify the `validation_split` paramater here in the example I used `0.25`. The rest of the paramaters are optional and are there if you need to augment or preprocess the images.

Under each of the generators you have to specify the path to the images under `directory`, x_col and y_col(based on your CSV file) so you would not need to use `image_dataset_from_directory` for this, only use that if your directory with the images follows the following format:

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......a_image_1.jpg
......a_image_2.jpg
...class_b/
......b_image_1.jpg
......b_image_2.jpg
```

### Example:

```
class Generators:
    def __init__(self, train_df, test_df):
        self.batch_size=32
        self.img_size=(64,64)
        
        # Base train/validation generator
        # Alter the paramaters here based on your needs!
        _datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale=1./255.,
            # Validation split is specified here!
            validation_split=0.25,
            featurewise_center=False,
            featurewise_std_normalization=False,
            rotation_range=90,
            width_shift_range=0.2,
            height_shift_range=0.2,
            horizontal_flip=True,
            vertical_flip=True
            )
        # Train generator
        self.train_generator = _datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=train_df,
            # Specify the path to the directory to read images from here!
            directory="../input/train/",
            x_col="id",
            y_col="label",
            has_ext=False,
            subset="training",
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            seed=42,
            shuffle=True,
            class_mode="categorical",
            target_size=self.img_size)
        print('Train generator created')
        # Validation generator
        self.val_generator = _datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=train_df,
            directory="../input/train/",
            x_col="id",
            y_col="label",
            has_ext=False,
            subset="validation",
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            seed=42,
            shuffle=True,
            class_mode="categorical",
            target_size=self.img_size)    
        print('Validation generator created')
        # Test generator
        _test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.)
        self.test_generator = _test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=test_df,
            directory="../input/train/",
            x_col="id",
            y_col='label',
            has_ext=False,
            class_mode="categorical",
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            seed=42,
            shuffle=False,
            target_size=self.img_size)     
        print('Test generator created')

        
# Create generators        
generators = Generators(train_df, test_df)
print("Generators created")
```